# Implementing a Node Removal Method in a Custom LinkedList Class in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I'm working on a custom LinkedList implementation in Java and facing challenges with my remove method. The goal is to remove a node from the linked list and update the index values associated with each node. I'm unsure if my logic for updating the node indexes is correct.

Here's the key part of my code:

```
public class LinkedList<E> {
    LLNode<E> head;
    LLNode<E> tail;
    int llSize;

    // Constructor and other methods...

    public E remove(E data) {
        LLNode<E> nodeToRemove = findNode(data); // Assuming there's a method to find the node
        // Logic to remove the node and update indexes...
    }
}

public class LLNode<E> {
    E obj;
    LLNode<E> previousPointer;
    LLNode<E> nextPointer;
    int index;

    // Constructor and other methods...
}
```

My specific issues are with the logic in the remove method, especially in updating the index of each node after a removal. I have written some code for different cases (like when removing the head, a middle node, or the tail), but I'm not confident it's working as expected.

How should I correctly update the index of each node in the linked list after a removal?

Are there best practices or common pitfalls I should be aware of in implementing this functionality?

The LinkedList class is a custom implementation, not the Java standard library's LinkedList.
I'm particularly struggling with the index updating part of the remove method.

Comment: In the case of Java's native linked list: "Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning or the end, whichever is closer to the specified index." This implies that there are no stored indexes, only the size of the list. This eliminates having to traverse the list to update stored indexes every time an element is inserted or removed.

Comment: I would suggest to use an INIT element instead of head and tail. So that init=new LLNode(null)
init.previousPointer = init.nextPointer = init;
With this you can safe many null checks in the operations.

Comment: @rcgldr Thanks for the feedback I did know that LinkedList do not have stored indexes, but the practice exercise that I'm working on requires me to code a method 'remove' that has an int parameter. That was the biggest confusion that I had with coding it. So the only way that I thought to address the Nodes was to attach an index to them. Even though Linked Lists normally don't have indexes. Other than that I'm not sure How I would go about this.

Comment: @YHapticY - What would be the benefit of storing indexes in the nodes, since it would still involve a traversal of the list in order to find a matching index?

Comment: @rcgldr I'm sorry I made a mistake. The 'remove' method doesn't require an index parameter. But there are other methods in the class that require an int index for the parameter, IE 'subList(int start, int stop)', 'get(int index)' That is why I coded up the Node class with an index parameter to keep track of the index/position that the Node is in in the List. How I can address the positions in the LinkedList without having the "index's" of the elements be tied to the Nodes and also use the provided method signatures of 'subList(int start, int stop)', 'get(int index)'?

Comment: @YHapticY - scan the list. If scanning forwards, the first node corresponds to index = 0. If scanning backwards, the last node corresponds to index = size - 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only need to renumber the nodes that follow *after* the removed node.

So:

```
public E remove(E data) {
    LLNode<E> nodeToRemove = new LLNode<>(data);

    if(head == null){
        return null;
    }

    // Adapt head and tail when necessary
    if(tail.getObj().equals(nodeToRemove.getObj())){
        tail = nodeToRemove.previousPointer;
    }
    if(head.getObj().equals(nodeToRemove.getObj())){
        head = nodeToRemove.nextPointer;
    }

    // Rewire the list so it skips the node to remove
    if(nodeToRemove.nextPointer != null){
        nodeToRemove.nextPointer.previousPointer = nodeToRemove.previousPointer;
    }
    if(nodeToRemove.previousPointer != null){
        nodeToRemove.previousPointer.nextPointer = nodeToRemove.nextPointer;
    }

    // Renumber the nodes that follow the removed node. 
    // (Those before it retain their index)
    LLNode<E> currentNode = nodeToRemove.nextPointer;
    int index = nodeToRemove.getIndex();
    while (currentNode != null) {
        currentNode.setIndex(index);
        index++;
        currentNode = currentNode.nextPointer;
    }
    
    this.llSize--;
    return nodeToRemove.getObj();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and this seems to be working well now, here are my changes.

get() Method

Added a count variable to compare with the passed parameter also my while comparison was checking current.next and not current and was getting null pointer.

```
public E get(int index) {
        LLNode<E> current = this.head;
        int count = 0;

        while(current != null){
            if(index == count) {
                return current.getObj();
            }
            current = current.nextPointer;
            count++;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

remove() Method

I used a while instead of the previous logic. and simplified the logic quite a bit.

```
 @Override
    public E remove(E data) {
        LLNode<E> current = this.head;
        while(current != null){
            if(current.getObj().equals(data)) {
              
                LLNode<E> prev = current.previousPointer;
                LLNode<E> next = current.nextPointer;
                if(prev != null) {
                    prev.nextPointer =  next;
                }
                if(next != null) {
                    next.previousPointer = prev;
                }
                llSize--;
                return current.getObj();
            }
            current = current.nextPointer;
        }
        return null;
    }
```